# Last Sunday to last Saturday date calculation (not in where statement, but select) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I see a lot of examples how to calculate dates from last Sunday to last Saturday in a where statement, but I didn't find any for the last week in SELECT statement.

if I need to have a formula [U_ONSALE_DATE] between last Sunday (03/06) and last Saturday (03/12) so that it dynamically changes each week (Sun - Sat).

I was trying to do it this way, but it didn't work as expected.

```
[U_ONSALE_DATE] BETWEEN  DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),f.[STARTDATE]) = -1 AND DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),f.[STARTDATE]) = -6
```

I have such a visual. Titles On Sale Last Week.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dUNU.jpg)

The way how I was calculating the dates before in a SELECT statement was with the CASE statement.

```
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY,0,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,[U_ONSALE_DATE])) 
<= DATEADD(DAY,-7,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE())) 
AND 
DATEADD(DAY,0,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,[U_ONSALE_DATE])) 
> DATEADD(DAY,-14,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()))
THEN 'Last Week On Sale Date'
ELSE NULL END AS 'Last Week On Sale Date'
```

However, this case statement basically takes titles from -7 (one week ago) to - 14 (2 weeks ago). But this is not actually what I need, I need this case statement to take [U_ONSALE_DATE] and take dates from Sunday to Saturday of the last week and it obviously will be changing each week. like today last Sun to Sat is 03/06 to 03/12.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have updated my initial explanation.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: If you need a query that will run from PowerBI and whatever limitations that imposes on T-SQL, you should make it clear in the question and via a tag that the solution needs to run in PowerBI.

Comment: is there something that can be changed in this "DECLARE @PrevSat date = DATEADD(DAY, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @d)+@@DATEFIRST%7), @d)" I think it doesn't like this line for some reason

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer to not use `DECLARE`, if that is in fact Power BI's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not clear what you want, but hopefully this will help. Determine the previous Saturday (regardless of `@@DATEFIRST` settings). You want an open-ended range, since probably `U_ONSALE_DATE` is `datetime`, so you want everything after and including the beginning of last Sunday and *before* the beginning of the current Sunday. So:

```
DECLARE @d date = GETDATE();
DECLARE @PrevSat date = DATEADD(DAY, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @d)+@@DATEFIRST)%7, @d);
    
SELECT [Last Week On Sale Date] = CASE 
  WHEN U_ONSALE_DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -6, @PrevSat) -- >= PrevSund
   AND U_ONSALE_DATE <  DATEADD(DAY, 1,  @PrevSat) -- <  CurrSund
  THEN 'Last Week On Sale Date' END
FROM ...
```

If PowerBI doesn't let you declare variables, well, shame on PowerBI:

```
SELECT U_ONSALE_DATE, [Last Week On Sale Date] = CASE 
  WHEN U_ONSALE_DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -6, d.PrevSat) -- >= PrevSund
   AND U_ONSALE_DATE <  DATEADD(DAY, 1,  d.PrevSat) -- <  CurrSund
  THEN 'Last Week On Sale Date' END
FROM ...
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, 
    CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))+@@DATEFIRST)%7, 
    CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))
) AS d(PrevSat);
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8e91ac64aacd35516b9b8f0795cc92c0)

Comment: This is exactly what I need. But I cannot use this part SELECT PrevSat = @PrevSat,
       PrevSund = DATEADD(DAY, -6, @PrevSat),
       CurrSund = DATEADD(DAY, 1,  @PrevSat); I have a different SELECT statement afterwards and I cannot run both of them.

Comment: @Papapariski That wasn't to use in the query; all you need is `@PrevSat`. The `SELECT ... PrevSund, CurrSund` was just to demonstrate what adding a day and subtracting 6 days does. Take the 2 declares and the final select and ignore the thing I did to demonstrate how it worked. That better?

Comment: thank you. However, when I am trying to add this SQL code to Power BI I am getting an error "Microsoft SQL: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
Incorrect syntax near ')'." Do you know where can be an issue?

Comment: @Papapariski Sorry, I don't know anything about PowerBI, is it possible PowerBI can call a stored procedure? Otherwise you may be confined to limitations in T-SQL syntax that I just don't know about.

Comment: 2nd code works just great. Thank you!!